# Is it possible to remove two for loops using numpy mask?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, nested-loops, numpy-ndarray

Hi I have two arrays `y_pred.shape : (64, 7, 5)` in which it has the prediction of 5 classifiers for 7 neighbours of 64 samples in the dataset and `y_true.shape :(64, 7)` in which the true label of 7 neighbours of 64 samples are kept. that I need to compute the Jaccard index using [sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html). The Jaccard index needs be calculated and saved into an array:

```
jacc_index = np.empty((np.size(neighbors,axis=0), self.n_classifiers)) # shape : (64, 7)
```

I am using two nested for loop to calculate the Jaccard index:

```
    for i in np.arange(np.size(neighbors,axis=0)):
        for index_clf, clf in enumerate(self.classifiers_):
            tanimoto_index[i,index_clf] = jaccard_score(y_true[i], y_pred[i,:,index_clf])
```

**Question**
In advanced array programming of numpy, it is possible to remove the for loops. I am not an expert in python programming, and wondering if it is possible to remove these nested loops by replacing with a specific command in `NumPy`?

Your expert suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering: from the description of the jaccard_score, shouldn't `y_pred` and `y_true` have the same shape? If I understand it right it just calculates the number of times where the prediction equals the truth divided by the size of the set, right?

Comment: @RolandDeschain yes true, that is why it is in two loops, the command `y_pred[i,:,index_clf]` is taking the prediction of first classifier once `index_clf =0` in the second loop, and the shape becomes `(64, 7)` which exactly the same shape of `y_true[i]`. I am comparing the `y_true[i] with the prediction of all 5 classifiers in the second loop. I hope it is clear

Comment: Are you trying to improve the performance or the elegance of your code?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters yes